# In CentOS , Tomcat deployed REST service Need to create Spring -ldap connection every time after server went idle

Tags: java, rest, tomcat7, centos6, spring-ldap

I have a spring REST app deployed in tomcat server. This application is using the spring-ldap template to create LDAP connection.

**The Problem is:** if Java application is idle (without having any request ) for around 1 min. LDAP connection is closed.For the next request, it needs to create a connection again, hence this leads to performance issue.(always it adds additional 5000ms to create connection)

The Same .war file is working without having this issue when it deployed it in Windows 8 server.This problem only happens when it deployed in CentOS 6 server.

Comment: is there not a setting? or for brute for schedule a `ping` of the ldap server every 30 seconds

Comment: at the moment we have not implemented any of os level configurations